# How to select certain columns from two different tables in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that share the PartNumber column, how can I select specific columns from both these tables?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT * FROM OrderDetails AND SELECT Stock FROM Items WHERE PartNumber = 44320
```

Comment: Use a `UNION (ALL)`?

Comment: Or maybe JOIN ?

Comment: If you need specific column, you should not use `*`.

Comment: If `PartNumber` is common to both tables, you probably want to `JOIN` the tables on that column.

Comment: @Luuk well I used `*` becuase I would like to select all from `OrderDetails`, but only want to select `Stock` from `Items`. So you believe `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is the solution?

Comment: [The Sins of SELECT *](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/finding-code-smells-using-sql-prompt-asterisk-select-list), the only rest I can say is you should follow a course in SQL. because that will give an answer to this question.

Comment: @Luuk yes master.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is by using a join query.

`SELECT * FROM OrderDetails INNER JOIN Stock ON Stock.StockId = OrderDetails.OrderDetails.Id;`

this is assuming that there are foreign keys

or you can do something like

`SELECT * FROM OrderDetails UNION ALL Select * FROM Stock`

Comment: You don't need foreign keys to be able to join. And `UNION` of course only works if both tables have identical schemas, and it doesn't sound like OP needs a union anyway

Comment: @xceing Do you mean ? `SELECT * FROM OrderDetails INNER JOIN Items ON Items.Code = OrderDetails.OrderDetails.Code` . Stock is not a table, its a column. Also HoneyBadger is right UNION wont work.